# Find Table of Contents from a pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, tableofcontents

I want to get the table of content of each of my document and based on previous questions I have this code:

```
from typing import Dict
import os
import fitz  # pip install pymupdf


def get_bookmarks(filepath: str) -> Dict[int, str]:
    # WARNING! One page can have multiple bookmarks!
    bookmarks = {}
    with fitz.open(filepath) as doc:
        toc = doc.get_toc()  # [[lvl, title, page, …], …]
        for level, title, page in toc:
            bookmarks[page] = title
    return bookmarks


for root, directories, files in os.walk("doc/"):
    for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        to_print = get_bookmarks(file_path)
        if to_print != {}:
            print(file_path)
        print(get_bookmarks(file_path))
```

So I iterate through all my documents and perform get_bookmarks(). But this method doesn't work for most of my documents (actually I am able to find the toc of only 1 document out of 50). Why does that happen and how can I solve? The structure of my pdf's are quite classical and the toc can be in various forms but it's clearly recognisable. For example:
[image]
[image]

Is there some way I can solve? Do you need more information to understand what's wrong?

Comment: "Bookmarks" refers to separate PDF metadata in a file which typically is shown to one side of a document in a PDF viewer. So, only one of your files has bookmarks, which is why `get_bookmarks` only works on that one. Your problem is not a simple one to be solved with a pre-built function, but in fact a complex text-extraction problem.

Comment: As has been said: what your are looking at is **_text_** on some page - probably also overlaid with some hyperlinks. The TOC of the PDF file however is a separate structure, that has nothing to do with that text: it may or may not coincide with it. Both things may exist or not independently from each other.

Comment: If you are adventurous enough, try to extract these text lines, and parse them. Then create a TOC list from this information and give the poor PDF a new TOC with `doc.set_toc(TOC)`.

Answer (score 2):

PDF is not a wysiwyg (what you see is what you get) format.

In order to understand why your code isn't working, you'll need to understand some technical details of PDF.

A PDF document is like a JSON datastructure. You have primitives (numbers, booleans, text) and aggregation types (lists, dictionaries). PDF also has a special type **streams**. A stream is able to represent binary data (such as images). PDF also has an explicit **reference** type. A reference is looked up in the **cross-reference table** (abbreviated to xref in PDF-nerd-circles). The xref essentially says "the object with ID 35 starts at bit 5464".

A PDF viewer starts reading from the bottom. There you'll find something like this:

```
<</Size 30 /Root 21 0 R /Info 1 0 R>>
```

This tells the reader that the `Catalog` dictionary (also called Root dictionary) can be found at reference 21. This dictionary tells the reader software where it can find all the important bits of the PDF.

This is an example of the `Catalog` of the same PDF.

```
21 0 obj
<</Type /Catalog /Pages 20 0 R>>
endobj
```

The `Pages` dictionary tells the reader where it can find the pages.

```
20 0 obj
<</Type /Pages /Count 6 /Kids [2 0 R 9 0 R 12 0 R 14 0 R 16 0 R 18 0 R]>>
endobj
```

This document has 6 pages, and the `Kids` array contains each of them, in order.

```
2 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Resources <</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/ExtGState <</G3 3 0 R
/G5 5 0 R>>
/Font <</F4 4 0 R
/F6 6 0 R>>>>
/MediaBox [0 0 596 842]
/Annots [7 0 R]
/Contents 8 0 R
/StructParents 0
/Parent 20 0 R>>
endobj
```

The `Page` dictionary contains information for rendering (such as the dimensions in `MediaBox`). And the contents of the page can be found in `Contents`.

```
8 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 7838>> stream
xœí]ÛŽ$Çq}ß¯˜`*3#"/€a€K‘z ...
```

Here `Contents` is an example of a `Stream`. And from the `Filter`, we can see its going to be compressed.

If we apply decompression, we'll find instructions (in a programming language called **postfix**).

In pseudo-code, you'll find something like:

```
go to 30, 80
set the active font to Helvetica, size 12
set the stroke color to black
draw the glyph for character "H"
go to 34, 80
draw the glyph for character "e"
etc
```

So, in its most basic format, the PDF document itself has no notion of structure. Which is why it can not be extracted. In fact, PDF doesn't even have a notion of "this text belongs together in a sentence/paragraph".

The PDF standard does allow you to add additional dictionaries that define things like bookmarks. But those are optional.

My guess is there are a few forces working against you:

1. Less information in the PDF means the PDF can be smaller. People tend to prefer smaller files (for emailing, storing, etc)
2. The PDF spec is huge. I imagine a lot of PDF libraries (or tools that convert to/from PDF) will start by implementing the basics (drawing text and lines), rather than immediately putting all these additional features in scope.